# What are filesystem dot attributes or filesystem.attributes files?

Tags: java, visual-sourcesafe

I got a Java project from another developer and I found several files with these two names strewn around the source folder:

```
vssver.scc
filesystem.attributes
```

I know the first one is from *Visual SourceSafe* but what about the second? Are these files from *Visual SourceSafe* too?

It's difficult to search this as *Google* simply ignores the dot character in between, even if I put the whole thing in quotes.

**Edit:** File contents are binary but mostly have references to classes from Java and libraries:

> [image: binary file contents]

Comment: What is inside the file? Can you open and post (an extract)? I guess it contains simply some *compatibility* information on how to set chmod programmatically, if the files are downloaded by hand (where these information may get lost) instead of using git where the information is held inside the files itself.

Comment: Seems to be a netbeans thing. I didn't find a good reference, but it's mentioned in the Javadoc of this method: http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-filesystems/org/openide/filesystems/FileUtil.html#extractJar(org.openide.filesystems.FileObject,%20java.io.InputStream)

Comment: @ConcurrentHashMap I have added the binary contents of the file.

Comment: Actually here is a nice reference, an old mailing list post from 2000: https://netbeans.org/projects/platform/lists/dev/archive/2000-08/message/170

Comment: @IsmailBadawi That looks like the right thing. Can you put all that into a nice answer? Be sure to quote the relevant texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, it looks to be a (presumably obsolete) Netbeans thing. The only real reference I could find is [this Netbeans mailing list post from August 2000](https://netbeans.org/projects/platform/lists/dev/archive/2000-08/message/170), which says it was used to store various IDE metadata about each file.

> It is created automatically when you modify some attributes of a file
>   using the IDE itself. [...] Every file (including directories) stores its
>   attributes in a filesystem.attributes located alongside it (in the
>   same containing directory). FileUtil.extractJar specially recognizes
>   filesystem.attributes in a JAR, so if you jar up your directory then
>   when it is extracted the jarred attributes will be applied to the
>   extraction folder.

The post mentions a "future reimplementation" using an XML-based filesystem, which I think has happened by now. [This later post](http://osdir.com/ml/java.netbeans.devel/2000-10/msg00052.html) mentions using the name `.nbattrs` to replace the old `filesystem.attributes`. I'm not a NetBeans user, but this seems to be what happened; for instance, I found an example in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/monkstone/1330788).